# Unable to apply user defined function on polars dataframe to create new variables

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to create new variables by applying `lambda` function but getting an **error**.

I have tried below code:

```
import polars as pl

df_test2 = pl.DataFrame(
                {
                    "a": [1, 8, 3],
                    "b": [4, 5, 9],
                }
 )
```

```
df_test2.with_columns(
    pl.all().apply(lambda x: (x - pl.mean(x))/x).suffix('_x')
)
```

```
df_test2.apply(lambda x: (x - pl.mean(x))/x)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What output are you expecting? Is this just an example as you can don't need apply to do this: `df.with_columns((pl.all() - pl.all().mean()).suffix('_x'))`

Comment: @jqurious code that works for me is `(df_test2
 .with_columns(
     ((pl.all() - pl.all().mean())/pl.all()).suffix('_x')))` . If you could add that in answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `.apply` to do this in Polars, you can use the expressions directly:

```py
df.with_columns((pl.all() - pl.all().mean()).suffix('_x'))
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ a_x  ┆ b_x  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ -3.0 ┆ -2.0 │
│ 8   ┆ 5   ┆ 4.0  ┆ -1.0 │
│ 3   ┆ 9   ┆ -1.0 ┆ 3.0  │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

> Using apply is strongly discouraged as you will be effectively running python “for” loops. This will be very slow. Wherever possible you should strongly prefer the native expression API to achieve the best performance.